# AWS-LINUX upgrade php from 5.4 to 7 on nginx web server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, php-7

I have an aws-linux ami. I'm currently using nginx as web server and php 5.4.
How I can upgrade to php 7? 
How I can also update mysql?
Thank you